# How to simplify : assign the value of multiple dropdownlists from a main dropdownlist selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core

**Explaination**

I have two dropdown_lists, the customers name and the second one, its preferred food.
When a customers makes an order, its preferred food will be shown on the second dropdown_list value (not editable).
What i want to do is have possibly, only two dropdownlists.

**Question**

Can the below code be simplified? How can it be done?

**The frontend**

```
                    <div class="form-group border">

    <select class="form-control text-primary border-0 select2-container fw-bold overflow-scroll" 
    style="max-height:320px;" id="patchid">
        <option selected>--- Customers ---</option>
    @foreach (var item in Model.PL)
        {
            <option id="@item.Id" cid="@item.FoodId" cin="@item.Food.Name">@item.CustomersName </option>
        }
</select>
    <select asp-for="Orders.CustomersId" class="form-control text-primary border-0 fw-bold " asp-items="ViewBag.CustomersId" id="custid" hidden>
        <option selected>--- Name ---</option>
    </select>
```

```
<div class="form-floating" >
        <select asp-for="Orders.FoodId" class="form-control bg-white text-primary fw-bold" asp-items="ViewBag.FoodId" id="foodid" hidden>
            <option selected>--- Preferred food ---</option>
        </select>

        <input class="form-control text-primary bg-white fw-bold" type="text" id="foodn" readonly />
 
</div>
```

**The javascript**

```
@section Scripts {
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/select2/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#patchid').select2({
        theme: "bootstrap-5",
        width: '100%',
        tags: true
    });

</script>

<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {

        $('#patchid').change(function () {
            var id = $(this).children('option:selected').attr("id")
            var cid = $(this).children('option:selected').attr("cid")
            var cin = $(this).children('option:selected').attr("cin")

            $('#custid').val(id);
            $('#foodid').val(cid);
            $('#foodn').val(cin);
        });
    })
</script>
```

}

**The backend**

```
   PL = await _context.Customers.Include(x => x.Food).ToListAsync();
  ViewData["CustomersId"] = new SelectList(_context.Customers, "Id", "CustomersName");
ViewData["FoodId"] = new SelectList(_context.Foods, "FoodId", "Name");
```

Comment: you could try load the food in read only field without additional drop down. `<option selected>--- Customers ---</option>@foreach (var item in Model.PL)  {<option value="@item.Id" data-cid="@item.FoodId" data-cin="@item.Food.Name">@item.CustomersName</option> }</select>
</div>
<div class="form-floating">
    <input class="form-control text-primary bg-white fw-bold" type="text" id="foodn" readonly placeholder="Preferred food" />
</div>`and set js: `on('change', function() {
            var cin = $(this).find('option:selected').data("cin");
            $('#foodn').val(cin);
        });`

Comment: I tried something analogous, but for some strange reason, onpost(), the customer Id was not recognised and it gave me an error. I was even thinking about some backend function, but for this it would be required RignalR or similar, and i do not want that. I am using select2, and it does not work well with this kind of solutions.

Comment: in my opinion select 2 will not affect with the hidden input field. for the error you could  check  hidden fields are properly named according to your backend's expected model binding or not.